# How to create a table resulting from joining of two or more table with this structure?

Tags: python, sqlite

Lets say I have two tables with the following structure and same values-

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|   TEACHER |   STUDENT |   CLASS | SEC   |   HB_a |   VHB_b |   HG_c |   VHG_d |
|-----------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------|
|         1 |         - |       - | -     |      1 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
|         - |         1 |      10 | D     |      1 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
|         - |         1 |       9 | D     |      1 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

> CLASS can go from 6-12 and SEC from A-Z,
>
> *There's nothing in STUDENT, CLASS, SEC while there's some value in TEACHER and Vice-versa .

Now i want to create a table joining two tables with exact structure and data given above... I.e, I want the result to be something like below-

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|   TEACHER |   STUDENT |   CLASS | SEC   |   HB_a |   VHB_b |   HG_c |   VHG_d |
|-----------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------|
|         2 |         - |       - | -     |      2 |       2 |      2 |       2 |
|         - |         2 |      10 | D     |      2 |       2 |      2 |       2 |
|         - |         2 |       9 | D     |      2 |       2 |      2 |       2 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work well, the output isn't what I want-

```py
__tbl_sy = f"""
CREATE TABLE <tbl>
AS SELECT CLASS, SEC, SUM(TEACHER), SUM(STUDENT), SUM(HB_a), SUM(VHB_b), SUM(HG_c), SUM(VHG_d)
FROM <tbl1>
UNION
SELECT CLASS, SEC, SUM(TEACHER), SUM(STUDENT), SUM(HB_a), SUM(VHB_b), SUM(HG_c), SUM(VHG_d)
FROM <tbl2>
GROUP BY CLASS, SEC
"""
Cursor.execute(__tbl_sy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sample data that you posted this will work:

```
select 
  sum(teacher) teacher, sum(student) student, 
  class, sec, 
  sum(hb_a) hb_a, sum(vhb_b) vhb_b, sum(hg_c) hg_c, sum(vhg_d) vhg_d
from (
  select * from tbl1  
  union all
  select * from tbl2
)  
group by class, sec
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2snXr9FRKRnkhtQwKTHAE9/2).
Results:

```
| teacher | student | CLASS | SEC | hb_a | vhb_b | hg_c | vhg_d |
| ------- | ------- | ----- | --- | ---- | ----- | ---- | ----- |
| 2       |         |       |     | 2    | 2     | 2    | 2     |
|         | 2       | 10    | D   | 2    | 2     | 2    | 2     |
|         | 2       | 9     | D   | 2    | 2     | 2    | 2     |
```

Comment: Well thank you,  it works now. And now i see the problem with my query.